# React native: how do I wait for a state to be set, before I call another state related operation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-state

I am writing a chat app. Users can search for other users, and then press the "Message" button. Then I navigate to `ChatScreen.js`. If both users have been messaging each other, I set the `chatId` variable accordingly. If they have not messaged each other before I dont create `chatId`, until the ery first message has been sent. When the first message is sent, I first, create new chat, store its properties (user ids, chatId, etc) in my db and then I sent the first message. The problem is that I store `chatId` as a state variable, and when I create the chat I call `setChatId(id)`. `setChatId()` is not synchronous call, so by the time when I need to send message with `sendText(text, chatId);` my `chatId` is `undefined` even though I have already created a chat and I have called `setChatId`.

How can I avoid this error? Ofc, I can check `if chatId == undefined` then calling `sendText(text, id)`, otherwise calling `sendText(text, chatId)`. Is there a better/neath way to avoid the `undefined` check?

Here is part of my code:

```
...

import {
  createChat,
} from "./actions";

...

function ChatScreen(props) {
  ...
  const [chatId, setChatId] = useState(props.route.params.chatId);
  ...

  const setupChat = async () => {
    try {
      await createChat(user.id, setChatId);
      props.fetchUserChats();
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error creating chat: ", error);
    }
  };

  async function handleSend(messages) {
    if (!chatId) {
      // creating chat
      await setupChat();
    }
    const text = messages[0].text ? messages[0].text : null;
    const imageUrl = messages[0].image ? messages[0].image : null;
    const videoUrl = messages[0].video ? messages[0].video : null;
    const location = messages[0].location ? messages[0].location : null;
    //assuming chatId is already setup but it is not
    if (imageUrl) {
      sendImage(imageUrl, chatId, setSendImageError);
    } else if (location) {
      sendLocation(location, chatId, setLocationError);
    } else if (videoUrl) {
      sendVideo(videoUrl, chatId, setSendImageError);
    } else {
      sendText(text, chatId);
    }

  }

...
}
```

My `createChat` function from `actions.js` file

```
export async function createChat(otherUid, setChatId) {
  let chatId = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid + "_" + otherUid;
  await firebase
    .firestore()
    .collection("Chats")
    .doc(chatId)
    .set({
      users: [firebase.auth().currentUser.uid, otherUid],
      lastMessage: "Send the first message",
      lastMessageTimestamp: firebase.firestore.FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    })
    .then(() => {
      console.log("doc ref for creatign new chat: ", chatId);
      setChatId(chatId);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      console.error("Error creating chat: ", error);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a state variable, I would advise you to use `useRef()`. This would be a good solution to your problem.Eg Define it this way
`const chatId = useRef(null)`,

then set it this way `chatId.current = yourChatId`

and get it this way `chatId.current`. I hope this solves your problem